# Building GCC make: *** [all] Error 2

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, makefile, g++

**I am trying to set up a cross-compiler for i686-elf on Ubuntu** following the [OSDev GCC Cross-Compiler Tutuorial.](http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler) However, the code to set up GCC fails to build every time. I know my sources are not out of date because I `sudo apt-get update`'d before doing anything.

**In order to get the packages I needed, I did:**

```
sudo apt-get install g++
sudo apt-get install make
sudo apt-get install bison
sudo apt-get install flex
sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev
sudo apt-get install libmpfr-dev libmpfr-doc libmpfr4 libmpfr4-dbg
sudo apt-get install mpc
sudo apt-get install texinfo
sudo apt-get install libcloog-isl-dev
```

I think there is no problem with that method?

Then, with **gcc-5.2.0** and **binutils-2.25.1** (in ubuntu, bintuils appears to not work with anything above that old version) I installed binutils just fine. I went to build gcc but when I typed in make, I got the following error:

**Unfortunately, I can't copy+paste 30 pages in, but this all the code near the end:**

```
checking command to parse nm output from gcc  -m32 object... failed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... /lib/cpp
checking for ANSI C header files... no
checking for sys/types.h... no
checking for sys/stat.h... no
checking for stdlib.h... no
checking for string.h... no
checking for memory.h... no
checking for strings.h... no
checking for inttypes.h... no
checking for stdint.h... no
checking for unistd.h... no
checking for dlfcn.h... no
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc  -m32 supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc  -m32 option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc  -m32 PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc  -m32 static flag -static works... no
checking if gcc  -m32 supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc  -m32 supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc  -m32 linker (ld -m elf_x86_64 -m elf_i386) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... configure: error: Link tests are not allowed after GCC_NO_EXECUTABLES.
Makefile:9590: recipe for target 'configure-zlib' failed
make[1]: *** [configure-zlib] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/david/scr'
Makefile:876: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

**And this is the part (right after that) where something really bad happens:**

```
checking dynamic linker characteristics... configure: error: Link tests are not allowed after GCC_NO_EXECUTABLES.
Makefile:9590: recipe for target 'configure-zlib' failed
make[1]: *** [configure-zlib] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/david/scr'
Makefile:876: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and how I would fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: [This message](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2012-07/msg00018.html) could be helpful to you.

Comment: @FUZxxl thanks! I will tell later if this worked.

Comment: @FUZxxl OMG THANKS I have **literally** spent over 50 hours on this, and it finally worked.

Comment: It was a pleasure to me. If you don't mind, would you write down the steps you took for future people with the same problem?

Comment: I fixed this issue by adding the flag "--with-system-zlib" to my first and second GCC build passes and it resolved the error for me. Make sure though you have the "zlib1g-dev" package installed. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 btw.

Comment: @fuz I answered the question but for some reason it doesn't exist anymore. Maybe at one point I accidentally deleted it? I'll write it again.

Comment: @DavidA I suspect there was a glitch when you tried to submit your answer. Try again and make sure the answer was actually submitted.

Comment: @fuz or DavidA, please add this as an answer - the answer that DavidA referred to remains non-existent.

Comment: Also, just to clarify, I believe the `--with-system-zlib` flag needs to be added to the `configure` command, not the `make` command.

Comment: I am not sure what you did to solve the problem. Please write an answer yourself!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was that I wasn't installing mpc from source.

Here is the finished file (`setup-gcc.sh`):

```
####################################
echo Stage 1 - Building Dependencies
####################################

# make a working directory
cd $HOME/Documents
rm -rf Cross
mkdir Cross
cd Cross

# install or update all apt-get dependencies
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get install gcc -y                 # not cross
sudo apt-get install g++ -y
sudo apt-get install make -y
sudo apt-get install bison -y
sudo apt-get install flex -y
sudo apt-get install gawk -y
sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev -y
sudo apt-get install libmpfr-dev libmpfr-doc libmpfr4 libmpfr4-dbg -y
sudo apt-get install mpc -y
sudo apt-get install texinfo -y            # optional
sudo apt-get install libcloog-isl-dev -y   # optional
sudo apt-get install build-essential -y
sudo apt-get install glibc-devel -y
sudo apt-get -y install gcc-multilib libc6-i386 -y

# download and unpack necessary files
wget http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/binutils/binutils-2.25.1.tar.gz
wget http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/gcc/gcc-5.3.0/gcc-5.3.0.tar.gz
wget http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/mpc/mpc-1.0.3.tar.gz
for f in *.tar*; do tar zvxf $f; done

# create installation directory
mkdir Install
export PREFIX="$HOME/Documents/Cross/Install"
export TARGET=i686-elf
export PATH="$PREFIX/bin:$PATH"

################################
echo Stage 2 - Building Compiler
################################

# install mpc
mkdir build-mpc
cd build-mpc
../mpc-1.0.3/configure --prefix="$PREFIX"
make -j2
make -j2 check
make -j2 install
cd ..

# install binutils
mkdir build-binutils
cd build-binutils
../binutils-2.25.1/configure --target=$TARGET --prefix="$PREFIX" --with-sysroot --disable-nls --disable-werror
make -j2
make -j2 install
cd ..

# install gcc
mkdir build-gcc
cd build-gcc
../gcc-5.3.0/configure --target=$TARGET --prefix="$PREFIX" --disable-nls --enable-languages=c,c++ --without-headers --with-mpc="$PREFIX"
make -j2 all-gcc
make -j2 all-target-libgcc
make -j2 install-gcc
make -j2 install-target-libgcc
```

Once you have it installed, you can run it with:

```
export PREFIX="$HOME/Documents/Cross/Install"
export TARGET=i686-elf
$PREFIX/bin/$TARGET-gcc --version
```

Unfortunately, doing this inside of an alias or bash script doesn't seem to properly launch it, so, unless this gets fixed, you might have to just store the script in a text file and copy-paste it into terminal every time you reboot.

To uninstall your cross-compiler, simply delete the `$HOME/Documents/Cross directory.`

As a final note, changing the installation directory or target is as easy as changing the value of `$PREFIX` or `$TARGET`, but I wouldn't recommend it, because you may run into other unexpected problems.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `--with-system-zlib`, it worked for me when I use `--disable-multilib` option.